# how to jump from page to other page in docx

Tags: python, docx

i am working with the **docx** library to parse some words documents, but i can't find how to jump from page to other page in the word document????

can any one have idea how to do that ???? and thank you

i already seen the documentation but i couldn't find any thing...  https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

```
from docx import Document
```

Answer (score 1):

A page is a type of [Section](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/sections.html#accessing-sections).

You can iterate over document sections:

```
document = Document()
for section in document.sections:
    print(section.start_type)
```

The [section types](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdSectionStart.html) can be as follows:

- CONTINUOUS

  - Continuous section break.
- NEW_COLUMN

  - New column section break.
- NEW_PAGE

  - New page section break.
- EVEN_PAGE

  - Even pages section break.
- ODD_PAGE

  - Section begins on next odd page.

Comment: sorry because i am new using the docs library, still can't get how to jump from page to an other page in my word document, and when i executed the code it give me NEW_PAGE (2). what that mean exactely ?

Comment: I know nothing about the docx library. I just looked up the documentation for you and posted it.

Comment: If you want to be able to refer to particular sections, you could [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) them so you know what index to use to look them up. But that's not really anything to do with `docx`, it's just how to write python. If you're struggling with that, you probably need to do a basic Python tutorial. See [Interactive Python Learning](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info).